# selenium python find elements output to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

Newbie here.

Need help on `Selenium Python, Find Elements, Pandas:`

**Codes** as follows:

```
array=[]
array=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//fl-list-item")
for e in array:
   print(e.text)
```

I can see the print(e.text) as follows: (there are 20 elements and here is the 1st one)

```
Convert a PDF in Word
$250 – 750 USD
Posted 6 minutes ago
We would like to have a (scanned) PDF file convert to a Word file
Data Entry
Excel
PDF
Word
Copy Typing
Fixed Price
28 Bids
0.0
```

Question: how do I get these as one row with headers using Pandas?

Went to numerous videos and kind of know bits and pieces but couldn't get the data into Pandas.

Appreciate help to newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you want to store each array item in a separate column and give it a header within the for loop. Here is how you can do that:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe with correct shape
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':['placeholder']})

# your array here
array = ['first','second','third','fourth']

# create an index for column headers
index = 1

# iterate through your array and set each column value
for item in array:
    df[index] = item
    index += 1

print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
         index      1       2      3       4
0  placeholder  first  second  third  fourth
```

Comment: Thanks Geom for that! It did get the array I had into pandas and produced the output as what you have indicated. Guess my next problem is to extract each element's content into columns. Will see if I can post a picture of the output for better illustration. Oh, looks like I can't post a screenshot.

Comment: Now pandas index 1 is storing the first element of the array. Just that, I need each line of data to be in separate column ie one row translate to one column. If pandas can do this easily, appreciate the guidance (pointing to video for learning is perfect for me). 

Convert a PDF in Word
$250 – 750 USD
Posted 6 minutes ago
We would like to have a (scanned) PDF file convert to a Word file
Data Entry
Excel
PDF
Word
Copy Typing
Fixed Price
28 Bids
0.0